# How to do a regexp in a waitForPopUp Command in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have popups with this name structure:

*static_dynamic_static*

The dynamic part changes each time I log in so my test cases fail each time. I thought about solving the problem with a regular expression like this:

**Command:** waitForPopUp

**Target:** regexp:static_.+_static

But this doesn't work. What do I do wrong? Is this even working. If not, is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you don't need to declare it as a regex within the target field, you should just be able to have the target as:

```
static_*_static
```

and that should do it

Comment: This does not work sadly. Not for the waitForPopUp Command and not for thr selectWindow command :(

Answer (score 0):

If you've got only one popup window you can use null as a target and test will take the first popup:

```
waitForPopup | null
```

The other option is to get dynamic part **before** popup opening. It is very likely that the dynamic part could be retrieved from the page. If so you can get it using storeEval, and than use like:

```
waitForPopup | javascript{'static'+storedVars['dynamic']+'static'}
```

If you can't store the dynamic part please provide an html of your page or only the part where the dynamic part mentioned.

I see that theoretically it could be possible to get all the names of your windows and than to use pattern in a loop to get the one.

Also (theoretically) it is possible to expand default waitForPopup function.

But the second way and especially the first are much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this might be to run a snippet of javascript to handle this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var myRe = new RegExp(&quot;^prefix.+&quot;, &quot;g&quot;); var mywin; windows=selenium.getAllWindowNames();for (i = 0; i &lt; windows.length; i++) { if(myRe.test(windows[i])) { mywin=windows[i]}&nbsp;&nbsp;};&nbsp;&nbsp;mywin;</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=${myWindow}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

That javascript isn't fully function (no null checking) but should help get you on the right track.